# How do I get the number of rows from a table?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I am simply trying to get the number of rows in a table to update a counter. I've tried:

```
getRowCount(callback) {
    this.db.all(`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pk_patients`, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            callback(rows[0].count);
        }
    });
}
```

I just get undefined. The table does have data in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pk_patients`

to `SELECT COUNT(*) as 'count' FROM pk_patients`

Comment: To add on this: I've never used `sqlite3`, but from the docs it looks like this would make more sense to use [`db.get`](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databasegetsql-param--callback) over `db.all`.
Then you can do: `this.db.get('...', (err, result) => result.count)`. Since there will only be one row returned from `COUNT`.

Comment: Thank you, that works great. Where might I find good documentation that teaches this?